# Generate 'year' variable for multiple files in a specific folder

Tags: stata

I want to use Stata to `generate` a variable `year` for many files in a folder.

Stata code:

```
clear

local folder_path "C:\Users\ksgao\Dropbox\Chingyuan RA work for DDP\6. Micro to macro datasets\1. Raw micro-to-macro data\CBP\19"

local ff : dir "`folder_path'" files "*.dta"
dis `"`ff'"'

foreach f of local ff {
    use "`folder_path'\`f'", clear
    local year = substr("`f'", 4, 2)
    gen year = 19 + real(year)
    save "`folder_path'\`f'", replace 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what problems exist with your code, but I can guess at two.

One is  following  a backslash with a local macro reference. The problem and its solution are discussed [here](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042). The other is referring to `year` before the variable is created.

Your code can be simplified and corrected in this way.

```
clear

cd  "C:\Users\ksgao\Dropbox\Chingyuan RA work for DDP\6. Micro to macro datasets\1. Raw micro-to-macro data\CBP\19"

local ff : dir . files "*.dta"
dis `"`ff'"'

foreach f of local ff {
    use "`f'", clear
    gen year = 19 + real(substr("`f'", 4, 2)) 
    save "`f'", replace 

}
```